# Java with MySQL Batch Update takes to long to process

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I created a test table on my MySQL database. The table only has 3 fields: `id`, `firstname`, `lastname`

Now I'm trying to bulk update the first name for the fist 50 000 records and it is taking way to long, more than 10 minutes (which by then I cancel the process) which I find not acceptable or something's wrong with my code.

Here's my code:

```
    public void testeInsertBatch() {

        PreparedStatement stat;
        try {

            InsertData.insertDataUsingSQLTest(connection, database, batchSize);

            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            String updateSQL = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET firstname = ? WHERE id = ?";
            stat = connection.prepareStatement(updateSQL);

            int aux = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 50000; i++) {

                stat.setString(1, "new name");
                stat.setInt(2, i+1);
                stat.addBatch();
                aux++;

                if(aux % 100 == 0) {
                    stat.executeBatch();
                    stat.clearBatch();
                }
            }

            //Execute the batch.
            int[] updateCounts = stat.executeBatch();
            stat.clearBatch();
            stat.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If in the for loop I change from 50 000 to 1 000 the update is done in an more or less acceptable amount of time (~30 seconds).

My question is, is this normal behaviour for a bulk update or is something wrong with my code's performance?

I'm running `MySQL 5.6.12` and the table is a `InnoDB` table

I'm using `JDBC` with `rewriteBatchedStatements=true`

Comment: 30 sec for 1000 * 50 = 25 Minutes, so if you assume that 30 sec are acceptable, than everything is fine :) How many entries are in the table, how big is it, how many RAM is available and how are innodb_buffer settings?

Comment: @KeschaSkywalker the table has 50 000 entries and available ram is around 1giga. The `innodb_buffer` is commented (`#`) on my `mysql.ini` file

Comment: You should setup your database. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size And could you post your create table query?